# call to undefined method DateTime::add method in php

Tags: php, datetime

I am using php 5.2.9 as a part of xampp installation. I am using codeigniter framework for my webapp. When I call upon DateTime::add, the `Call to undefined method` error is displayed. My code is...

```
$date_now = new DateTime();
$formatted_date = $date_now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$expiry_date = $date_now->add(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
```

The error being displayed is...

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::add() in C:\webapps\first\system\application\models\model_first.php on line 25
```

How can I resolve this? The `DateTime::format` method works fine here.

Regards

Comment: +1: had the exact same problem, even had to use it to calculate an expiration date...! :)

Comment: I had a similar problem but I was trying to convert an empty date.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you minimally need PHP version 5.3.0 or higher for the add function. See the following link for more info: [PHP manual - DateTime::add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

Comment: @prodigitalson - Thanks. Also I found this function `strtotime()` which I am using now.

Comment: I did use DateTime::modify - http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php. Worked perfectly.