# is DateTime a pre-defined function or method in php?

Tags: php

guys im helping someone with his php code. but i  cant seem to figure out whats wrong with this code:

[image]

the system is fine in LOCALHOST. but when i uploaded it to a free hosting (000webhost.com) it gives me this error:

**"Fatal error: Call to undefined method DateTime::add() in /home/a5927002/public_html/thesis2/lib/functions.php on line 273"**

so i look for a function or class DateTime, i cant find it anywhere. but its working fine in localhost. any ideas guys?

Comment: No need to duplicate the question. It's already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938741/call-to-undefined-method-datetimeadd-method-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your local compiled with php 5.3 or greater but your shared host is compiled with php 5.2 or lower.You need PHP version 5.3.0 or higher for the add function. See the following link for more info:

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php)

DateTime::modify() is an alternative when using PHP 5.2 (php.net). For example you can add 1 day to a specific date using modify function:

```
$date = date_create('2006-12-12');
date_modify($date, '+1 day');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

Comment: so what youre saying sir is 000webhost.com doesnt support php5?

Comment: no it does support php 5, but maybe it does not support php 5.3 or you may have ask them to compile php 5.3 or greater for you

Comment: I searched it looks like that 000webhost.com still runs PHP 5.2.17. And that should be the case

Comment: DateTime::modify() is an alternative when using PHP 5.2.

Comment: does it do the same thing as add()? @MIIB

Comment: It is an alternative. For example you can date_modify($date, '+1 day'); add one day to your date with this function.

Comment: out of topic question.. do you know any free webhosting site that supports 5.3+ version of php? please im really tired here. spent 1 hour searching for a free webshosting site

Comment: No sorry. I hope you'll find soon